# how to provision an account automatically on a service in ITIM 5.1?

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I am new to ITIM, when ever a new user is created in ITIM, i want an account for that ITIM user to be created on a particular service automatically.  Please advice what steps to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new provisioning policy (or edit the one you created automatically when creating the service).  Within the policy, set an entitlement for the service and set the provisioning option to automatic.  On the service set the policy enforcement to correct.  Note that any new (or existing) accounts will receive the service as soon as you do that.  Make sure in the provisioning policy entitlement that you also set what attributes on the service account that you want set when the account is provisioned.